# Error when attempting to beautify PHP

Tags: php, macos, atom-editor

I'm building a website using PHP files and when I try to beautify the editor contents using Atom Beautify, I get an error that says `Could not find 'php-cs-fixer'. The program may not be installed.`:

[image]

I manually installed the package, but I've read that there's an issue relating to Atom not getting the user's `$PATH` when launched as an application, but I can't seem to understand how to get around this.

I'm running Atom 1.8.0 on Mac and all packages are up-to-date. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Download [this](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/) and edit Atom Beautify's settings for the php-cs-fixer by specifying the full path.